# W10 cant access WS2008 file shares

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, windows-server-2008-r2

**I have the following setup:**

Server: Proliant series, with my required folders shared with 'Administrators', WS2008

Clients:
2 Laptops, W10 Home installation |
1 Desktop, W10 Pro installation

All are connected to the same router, there is only 1 router which is also our internet gateway

**Previously**

Whenever I wanted to retrieve or store files on the server, I would navigate to it through explorer \MY-SERVER\ and be prompted for login credentials. I provided the Administrator credentials and I could then see and interact with the file shares, as expected. This was true of all clients on the network.

**Changes**

Yesterday an order for a new mobo/cpu arrived for the Desktop. After installing these I flattened the boot drive and reinstalled W10 (for good house keeping)

**Now**

If I try to access the server (nav to \MY-SERVER) I am presented with the following message: 
"Windows cannot access \MY-SERVER\

You do not have permission to access \MY-SERVER. Contact your network administrator to request access"

It is not even prompting me for login credentials. Whats curious is that if I navigate to a specific shared folder, eg \MY-SERVER\stuff, then I AM prompted to login (after a long pause), but the login dialog is captioned "Access denied", and providing the correct login credentials presents a similar Network Error message.

The server also does not appear in the list of network places on the Desktop. The other clients (2 W10 laptops) can still see and access the Server as normal.

**Notes**

- The desktop can reach the server through ping and Remote Desktop (I
  would just live with it and copy files through the tsclient share
  which appears during an RDP session, but I cannot stream files this
  way).
- The server has not stale credentials in Credential Manager
- All systems are in the same workgroup (WORKGROUP)
- Reg keys for 'restrictanonymous' are set to 0, although this surely would not affect an authenticated login anyway?

What am I doing wrong? Why is the W10 Desktop not able to access the shares in the same way the other W10 clients can?

Answer (score 1):

So I had spent all of the previous evening facing this problem, decided to call it a night and this morning constructed my question. Only an hour (ish) later did I discover that the ethernet controller in device manager had a generic driver installed for it. Sailing through the manufactuerers website I was able to get a full branded (proper?) driver for the onboard ethernet.

Having installed that now, the problem has vanished and I can access the server shares again. I find it difficult to swallow that this was the cause, when so much other networking functionality was unaffect (internet usage, RDP etc...) but I suppose anything is possible with driver issues....

Perhaps not the most useful Q&A for superuser, but just in case anyone else faces the exact same problem... there you go!